# C# process can not execute batch file (contain timeout command) correctly

Tags: c#, process

I'd like to execute a batch file without showing terminal window
and I need to get the standard output contents.
Here is the batch file:

```
timeout /T 5
exit 0
```

Below is my partial C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool ShowTerminal = true;

    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    string ExecContent = "\"" + args[0] + "\"";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + ExecContent;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = ShowTerminal;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = !ShowTerminal;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = !ShowTerminal;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = !ShowTerminal;
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

I found that variable ShowTerminal set true, then everything is going well
except I can not get standard output contents

But if variable ShowTerminal set false, timeout command will be skipped

Is there any solution for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Why not redirect the `STDOUT` to a file like `cmd.exe > output.txt`

Comment: There are hundred of batch file need to execute parallel, redirection may not a good way...

Comment: Instead of `proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = ShowTerminal`, have you tried `proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = !ShowTerminal`?

Comment: Ignore proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = ShowTerminal will cause an exception: System.InvalidOperationException :(

Answer (score 0):

If you specify "redirect" options you should also provide their redirection streams (STDIN, STDOUT) and ensure they are being emptied/read/processed as CMD would expect.

Chances are good that 'timeout' is failing to detect any STDIN/STDOUT and therefore performs a noop.